# Can I grant view all access to some user for certain record types

Tags: record-type, access

Say for cases, I just want to grant view all access to a group of users to some certain record types but not other record types. How should I achieve this? I have tried to grant view all access to limit access to some record types but doesn't seem to work well. User can view all the cases in that case. How should I achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to make a sharing rule that uses RecordTypeId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making access to the object `Private` in Sharing Settings. Then, build up view access to that object using Sharing Rules (also in Sharing Settings).

Also make sure that the users in question don't have `View All Data` or `Modify All Data` in the profile/permission set; nor View All or Modify All in their profile/permission sets for the object in question

**Example for Object MyObject**:

Recordtype = 'a' grant read access to members of a particular role or public group
Recordtype = 'b' grant read access to all internal users